# How to run Bitcoin Core as onion service on Windows, Ubuntu and Android?

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor

Have you tried running Bitcoin Core listening on Tor on different platforms? What are your experiences, issues that you faced, hacks, workarounds etc.?

Answer (score 1):

**Windows**

You can follow one of the steps from 2 and 3. Step 2 uses cookie for authentication and Step 3 uses password.

1. Download and Install Bitcoin Core from https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.20.1/bitcoin-0.20.1-win64-setup.exe
2. Edit the `bitcoin.conf` file, enter the below things and save it. Default location of the file is `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf`

```
listen=1

debug=1

logips=1

testnet=1

listenonion=1

onlynet=onion

proxy=127.0.0.1:9150

torcontrol=127.0.0.1:9151
```

- How to setup cookie auth for Tor control?

Open `C:\Users\Prayank\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc` and add below line:

`HCookieAuthentication 1`

3. IGNORE THIS STEP IF YOU ALREADY DID STEP 2. Edit the `bitcoin.conf` file, enter the below things and save it. Default location of the file is `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf`

```
listen=1

debug=1

logips=1

testnet=1

listenonion=1

onlynet=onion

proxy=127.0.0.1:9150

torcontrol=127.0.0.1:9151

torpassword=XYZ
```

*XYZ: Replace it with your password in plain text*

- How to setup password for Tor control?

Open command prompt/PowerShell and run the below commands:

`cd "C:\Users\Prayank\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor"`

`tor --hash-password "XYZ" >torhash.txt`

Open torhash.txt file, copy the last line which has below content, paste in `C:\Users\Prayank\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc` and save it:

`HashedControlPassword 16:1CEDITEDOMERANDOMSHITCF8EBCD9A50CLOLCDACF`

Run the below commands in command prompt or PowerShell to ensure connection with Tor control works:

`telnet 127.0.0.1 9151`
`AUTHENTICATE "XYZ"`

4. Launch [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/9.5.4/torbrowser-install-win64-9.5.4_en-US.exe)
5. Launch Bitcoin Core Wallet (Testnet) using the shortcut with a green icon or run `"C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -testnet` in command prompt or PowerShell and change the path accordingly
6. Run `getnetworkinfo` in console window and check the `localaddresses`. Check if `testnet3/onion_private_key` file is created and analyze the logs in debug.log file.

[image: Bitcoin-Core-Tor-Windows]

**Ubuntu**

You can follow one of the steps from 2 and 3. Step 2 uses cookie for authentication and Step 3 uses password.

1. Download [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.20.0/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz) and run the below commands:

`tar xzf bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`

`sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-0.20.0/bin/*`

`/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt`

2. Edit the `.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` file, enter the below things and save it.

```
listen=1

debug=1

logips=1

testnet=1

listenonion=1

onlynet=onion

proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
```

- How to setup Tor?

`sudo apt install tor`

Open `/etc/tor/torrc` and add below lines:

`ControlPort 9051`

`CookieAuthentication 1`

`CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1`

Restarts Tor: `sudo /etc/init.d/tor restart`

Add user to Tor group: `sudo usermod -a -G debian-tor <username>`

Run Bitcoin Core: `/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt`

3. IGNORE THIS STEP IF YOU ALREADY DID STEP 2. Edit the `bitcoin.conf` file, enter the below things and save it.

```
listen=1

debug=1

logips=1

testnet=1

listenonion=1

onlynet=onion

proxy=127.0.0.1:9150

torpassword=XYZ
```

*XYZ: Replace it with your password in plain text*

- How to setup password for Tor control?

Open command terminal and run the below commands:

`torpass=$(tor --hash-password "my-tor-password")`

`printf "HashedControlPassword $torpass\nControlPort 9051\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/tor/torrc`

4. Run `getnetworkinfo` in console window and check the `localaddresses`. Check if `testnet3/onion_private_key` file is created and analyze the logs in debug.log file.

[image: debug-log]

[image: Bitcoin-Core-Tor-Ubuntu]

**Android**

Download, Install and Run either [ABCore](https://github.com/greenaddress/abcore) or [Nayuta Core](https://github.com/nayutaco/NayutaCore).

[image: Nayuta-1] [image: Nayuta-2]
[image: Nayuta-3]

I have selected [Bitcoin Knots](https://bitcoinknots.org/) in the settings of ABCore however there is an option to use Bitcoin Core as well.

[image: ABCore-1][image: ABCore-4]
[image: ABCore-3][image: ABCore-2]