# What settings required to privately run bitcoin core on tails?

Tags: bitcoin-core, privacy, tor

I am running bitcoin-core on TailsOS which seems to work out of the box.  I think TailsOS blocks all unsafe requests but I would like to know what settings I should enable to run it really privately.  So far I start my node via

```
$ ./bitcoin-qt onlynet=onion
```

Is anything else required?  In [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/70070/112106) I read about a bunch of other settings but feel that isn't required on tails, correct?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98913/how-to-run-bitcoin-core-as-onion-service-on-windows-ubuntu-and-android

Comment: Thank you @Prayank but that answer seems to be also largely not tails specific so most settings are likely not applicable.

Comment: I will try using bitcoin core on Tails and share things later

Comment: e.g. tails disables UDP and prevents DNS leaks in general so I don't see that setting is required. https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Tor_enforcement/DNS/
In fact, my feeling is that bitcoin core does not need any non-default settings in tails.